# Unittest: new test cases for new pairs of numbers

Tags: python, python-unittest

I solved a task from [https://www.codewars.com/kata/59ccf051dcc4050f7800008f/python][1]

Here is my code:

```
import math
def buddy(start, limit):
    for n in range(start, limit + 1):
        m = s(n)
        if m > n and n == s(m):
            return [n, m]

    return None

def s(n):
    s = 0
    for i in range(2, round(n ** 0.5)):
        if n % i == 0:
            s += i
            s += n // i

    return s
```

For buddy(48, 50)) the output is: [48, 75]

For buddy(2177, 4357)) the output is: None

Now I want to write a unittest for my code.

Here is my sample:

```
import unittest
from buddy_pair import buddy

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_buddy_pair(self):
        pair = buddy(48, 50)
        self.assertEqual(pair, [48, 75])

    def test_buddy_None(self):
        pair = buddy(2177, 4357)
        self.assertEqual(pair, None)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Now I have a question. Am I doing the right testing and should I always write a new function for a new pair number testing? Also appreciate if you advice some test refactoring as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write them separately because you can then run then separately or run then altogether according to your needs.

If you write them in one function then you will have to adjust code when only want to test one of the results.
And there is 1 error in the code.

Should be

```py
    def test_buddy_pair(self):
        pair = buddy(48, 50)
        self.assertEqual([48, 75], pair)
```

The expectation should be the first parameter.